# NSSet property returning count of 1 when added to CoreData via Mantle

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, github-mantle

so I have an object with several properties that I want to add to coredata however I'm using the Mantle framework that I am not too familiar with.

My Object(.h):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RTModel.h"

@import CoreLocation;

@class RTPhoto;
@class RTContact;
@class RTUser;

@interface MyInteraction : RTModel <NSCopying, MTLJSONSerializing>

+ (NSManagedObject *)managedObjectWithIdentifier:(NSNumber *)identifier;
- (NSManagedObject *)managedObject;


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *longitude;

@property (strong, nonatomic) RTUser *user;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *createdByID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *createdByLabel;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *interactedWithLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *publicShareURLString;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *photos;

- (void)addPhotosObject:(RTPhoto *)photo;

@end
```

My Object(.m):

```
#import "OUTInteraction.h"
#import "RTComment.h"
#import "RTPhoto.h"
#import "RTUser.h"
#import "RTContact.h"
#import "OUTCoreDataController.h"
#import "OUTInteractionsController.h"

@interface MyInteraction () <UIActionSheetDelegate>

@end

@implementation MyInteraction

@synthesize identifier = _identifier;
@synthesize createdAt = _createdAt;
@synthesize updatedAt = _updatedAt;

- (void)deleteWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSError *))completion
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self managedObject];

    if (!managedObject) {
        completion(nil);
    };

    [[[MyCoreDataController sharedController] persistenceController] deleteObject:managedObject
                                                                saveContextAndWait:YES
                                                                        completion:^(NSError *error) {
                                                                            completion(error);
                                                                        }];
}
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return [[super JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey] mtl_dictionaryByAddingEntriesFromDictionary: @{
                                                                                             @"createdByID" : @"created_by_id",
                                                                                             @"createdByLabel" : @"created_by_label",
                                                                                             @"interactedWithLabel" : @"interacted_with_label",
                                                                                             @"interactionType" : @"interaction_type",
                                                                                             @"latitude" : @"latitude",
                                                                                             @"longitude" : @"longitude",
                                                                                             @"formID" : @"form_id",
                                                                                             @"formEntries" : @"form_entries",
                                                                                             @"interactedWithCity" : @"interacted_with_city",
                                                                                             @"interactedWithRegion" : @"interacted_with_region",
                                                                                             @"publicShareURLString" : @"share_url",
                                                                                             @"photos" : @"images"
                                                                                             }];
}

#pragma mark - Photos

- (void)addPhotosObject:(RTPhoto *)photo
{
    if (!photo) return;

    NSMutableSet *mutablePhotos = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:self.photos];

    [mutablePhotos addObject:photo];
    self.photos = [mutablePhotos copy];
}


- (BOOL)hasPhotoToDisplay
{
    if (!self.photos) return NO;
    if ([[self.photos allObjects] count] > 0) return YES;

    return NO;
}

#pragma mark - JSON Transformers

/// @note used by Mantle
+ (NSValueTransformer *)photosJSONTransformer
{

    return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^id(NSArray *array) {
        NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [NSMutableSet set];

        [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *JSON, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            RTPhoto *item = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[RTPhoto class]
                                      fromJSONDictionary:JSON
                                                   error:&error];
            if (error) DDLogError([error description], nil);
            [mutableSet addObject:item];
        }];
        NSLog(@"mutable set");
        return mutableSet;

    } reverseBlock:^id(NSSet *set) {
        NSLog(@"all objects");

        return [set allObjects];
    }];
}

/// @note used by Mantle
+ (NSValueTransformer *)commentsJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^id(NSArray *array) {
        NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [NSMutableSet set];

        [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *JSON, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            RTComment *item = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[RTComment class]
                                        fromJSONDictionary:JSON
                                                     error:&error];
            if (error) DDLogError([error description], nil);
            [mutableSet addObject:item];
        }];

        return mutableSet;

    } reverseBlock:^id(NSSet *set) {
        return [set allObjects];
    }];
}

/// @note used by Mantle
+ (NSValueTransformer *)contactsJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^id(NSArray *array) {
        NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [NSMutableSet set];

        [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *JSON, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            RTComment *item = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[RTContact class]
                                        fromJSONDictionary:JSON
                                                     error:&error];
            if (error) DDLogError([error description], nil);
            [mutableSet addObject:item];
        }];

        return mutableSet;

    } reverseBlock:^id(NSSet *set) {
        return [set allObjects];
    }];
}


/// @note used by Mantle
+ (NSValueTransformer *)formEntriesJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^id(NSArray *entryDictionaries) {
        NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet set];
        [entryDictionaries enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *entryDict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            RTInteractionFormEntry *entry = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[RTInteractionFormEntry class]
                                                      fromJSONDictionary:entryDict
                                                                   error:&error];
            [set addObject:entry];
        }];

        return set;
    } reverseBlock:^id(NSSet *set) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
        [set enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(RTInteractionFormEntry *entry, BOOL *stop) {
            [array addObject:[entry jsonDictionary]];
        }];

        return array;
    }];
}

/// @note used by Mantle
+ (NSValueTransformer *)userJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer mtl_JSONDictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:[RTUser class]];
}

/// @note used by Mantle
+ (NSValueTransformer *)interactionTypeJSONTransformer
{
    return [NSValueTransformer mtl_valueMappingTransformerWithDictionary:@{
                                                                           @"email" : @(kRTInteractionTypeEmail),
                                                                           @"check_in" : @(kRTInteractionTypeCheckIn),
                                                                           @"note" : @(kRTInteractionTypeNote),
                                                                           @"meeting" : @(kRTInteractionTypeMeeting)
                                                                           }];
}
#pragma mark - Core Data

+ (NSString *)managedObjectEntityName
{
    return @"Interaction";
}

+ (NSSet *)propertyKeysForManagedObjectUniquing
{
    return [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"identifier"]];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)managedObjectKeysByPropertyKey
{
    return [[super managedObjectKeysByPropertyKey] mtl_dictionaryByAddingEntriesFromDictionary:@{
                                                                                                 @"metadata" : [NSNull null],
                                                                                                 @"identifier" : @"interactionIdentifier",
                                                                                                 }];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)relationshipModelClassesByPropertyKey
{

    return [[super relationshipModelClassesByPropertyKey] mtl_dictionaryByAddingEntriesFromDictionary:@{
                                                                                                        @"comments" : [RTComment class],
                                                                                                        @"formEntries" : [RTInteractionFormEntry class],
                                                                                                        @"photos" : [RTPhoto class],
                                                                                                        @"contacts" : [RTContact class],
                                                                                                        @"user" : [RTUser class]
                                                                                                        }];
}
#pragma mark - Actions

- (void)delete
{
    [[MyInteractionsController controller] deleteInteraction:self
                                                      success:^{

                                                      } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                                          DDLogError([error description], nil);
                                                      }];
}

+ (NSManagedObject *)managedObjectWithIdentifier:(NSNumber *)identifier
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[MyInteraction managedObjectEntityName]];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"interactionIdentifier == %@", identifier];
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[MyCoreDataController sharedController] managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                           error:&error];
     NSLog(@"Results: %@", results);
    if (error) {
        DDLogError(@"Error fetching managed object: %@", [error description]);
    }

    return [results firstObject];
}

- (NSManagedObject *)managedObject
{
    return [MyInteraction managedObjectWithIdentifier:self.identifier];
}

- (void)mergeValuesForKeysFromManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject
{


    if ([managedObject valueForKey:@"photos"]) {
                NSMutableSet *combinedPhotos = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:self.photos];
        for (NSManagedObject *photoManagedObject in [managedObject valueForKey:@"photos"]) {

            RTPhoto *photo = [MTLManagedObjectAdapter modelOfClass:[RTPhoto class]
                                                 fromManagedObject:photoManagedObject
                                                             error:nil];
            if (photo.identifier || photo.localImageData || photo.imageDataPendingUpload) {
                [combinedPhotos addObject:photo];
            }
        }

        self.photos = [combinedPhotos copy];
    }
}



@end
```

Basically the problem I'm having when adding the whole object to CoreData
via Mantle is that everything gets added except when it reaches the photos property which is a NSSet it only adds one of the objects, usually the last one.

Here is when the object is added to the context using Mantle(in another file):

```
[MTLManagedObjectAdapter managedObjectFromModel:interaction
                               insertingIntoContext:self.context
                                              error:&coreDataError];
```

If someone has any clue as to why there is only one photos object being added under the "photos" key. I'm unfamiliar with how mantle handles toMany relationships and how to get all of the children added. Thanks

Comment: Well it doesn't replace it with a set of one object. It adds another object before it replaces the self.photos so after every use of that method the count does increase. The problem is when it goes in to the Mantle framework and it only saves one of the photos.

Comment: (Comment deleted) Oh, you're right.  You can use `mutableCopy` for clarity there rather than setWithSet.